# Unique collection in Laravel

Tags: php, loops, laravel-5

I need to find out unique value. So I tried bellow code. It is through undefined variable error.

Controller:

```
$employee = Employee::all();
Return view ('page', compact('employee'));
```

Page view:

```
$uniqueEmpLoc = $employee->unique('location')->values()->list('location')->toArray();
@Foreach($uniqueEmpLoc as $empLoc)
  {{ $empLoc }}
 //this is select box used for search 
@endforeach

//Display Entire data
@foreach($employee as @employee)
     //Display all value
@endforeach
```

But I got an `uniqueEmpLoc` is undefined error. I'm using LARAVEL 5.1. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: 1) `compact(employee)` should be `compact('employee')`. 2) On your view page you'll receive it like `$employee`

Comment: Oops am sry. @uchiha. It was typing error.

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your code:

1. I don't think `compact(employee)` would work. Shouldn't that suppose to be `compact('employee')` ?
2. In Blade, there is no need of putting curly braces at all. Remove them.

Try out the following:

```
$employees = Employee::unique('locations')->values()->list('location')->toArray();
return view('page', compact('employees'));
```

And then in your view:

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
    {{ $employee }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ya thanks. But first I have retrieved all values from db and pass is to the view page. There I'm displaying entire values.Additionally In that view page I have set one search box which contain location without repeated value. Thats why I have reuse same collection for view data and search, which passed from controller. So plz say how to handle this situation!

Comment: Ya your code is working fine. But I need to pass entire values to view page, from that I have to filter the value depands on location. Plz help me to solve my prob.

Comment: You can use jQuery plugins, there are many with what you are looking for.. Just google it, and you will be done.. To name some: http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ and https://select2.github.io

Comment: Sure. But Whether we can't use collection in view?

Answer (score 1):

Use this query in controller

```
$employees = Employee::distinct()->list('location')->toArray();
return view('page', compact('employees'));
```

In view

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
    {{ $employee }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks @smartrahat. But I need to send entire data to view page. From that compact data, I need to display distinct location values in select box in view page. Instead of query one more time, how to Distinct value from that compact value.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers here, this code should be in the controller. You shouldn't be doing logic in the views.

In the controller do:

```
$uniqueEmpLoc = $employee->unique('location')->values()->list('location')->toArray();
$employee = Employee::all();
Return view ('page', compact('employee', 'uniqueEmpLoc'));
```

The reason your code isn't working is the line that defines `$uniqueEmpLoc` is interpreted by blade as text, not code.

If you *really* want to do that in the view, you need to wrap it in `@php` tags.

```
@php
$uniqueEmpLoc = $employee->unique('location')->values()->list('location')->toArray();
@endphp
@Foreach($uniqueEmpLoc as $empLoc)
  {{ $empLoc }}
 //this is select box used for search 
@endforeach
```